# Steps to install MariaDB (MySQL) database files in NFS share, and run the service as a regular user (Linux)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've been looking for instructions but couldn't find a complete instruction set for the following:

1. Install MariaDB (MySQL) database and logs in an NFS share
2. Run MariaDB daemon as  a regular user defined in NIS

Using:

- Linux Ubuntu 14.04
- MariaDB 10.2.5

After reading many posts, and doing some trial & error, I came up with the steps listed below.  **I'd like to know if something is missing or wrong ??**

**1- Create directory in NFS:**

```
mkdir /nfs_dir/data -p
mkdir /nfs_dir/logs -p
chmod 700 /nfs_dir/data
chmod 750 /nfs_dir/logs
chown nisuser:nisgroup ...
```

**2- Crate run dir in local drive:**

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/mariadb
sudo chown nisuser:nisgroup /var/run/mariadb
sudo chmod 755 /var/run/mariadb
```

**3- Install MariaDB**

Instructions from download.mariadb.org

**4- `sudo service mysql  stop`**

**5- Create database files in NFS:**
    sudo mysql_install_db --user=nisuser --datadir/nfs_dir/data

**6- Edit MariaDB config** (below, only the edited lines are shown, others left as default):

```
sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf

[client]
socket = /var/run/mariadb/m.sock

[mysql_safe]
socket = /var/run/mariadb/m.sock

[mysqld]
user = nisuser
pid-file = /var/run/mariadb/m.pid
socket  = /var/run/mariadb/m.sock
datadir = /nfs_dir/data
log_warnings = 1
log_error = /nfs_dir/logs/error.log
log_bin = /nfs_dir/logs/mysql-bin.log
```

**7 - Update the MySQL Init script**

```
sudo vi /etc/init.d/mysql
```

Replace the test line as follows:

```
test -e /var/run/mariadb || install -m 755 -o nisuser -g nisgroup -d /var/run/mariadb
```

**8 - Update Debian config file**

```
sudo /etc/mysql/debian.cnf

[client]
socket = /var/run/mariadb/m.sock

[mysql_upgrade]
socket = /var/run/mariadb/m.sock
```

**9- Create debian-sys-main user** in mysql > user table

```
create user 'debian-sys-main'@'localhost' identified by 'password_from_debian_file'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to 'debian-sys-main'@'localhost' with GRANT OPTION;
```

**10 - Restart MariaDB**

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: What about specific settings to NFS share? (Like here [https://kb.netapp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1004952](https://kb.netapp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1004952) )

Comment: Not closely related to the actual question, but: we've seen odd problems when having MariaDB/MySQL data on NFS over the years. While most such installations seem to work fine, there can be odd problems with such setups that are hard to diagnose.

Especially when having NFS client and server implementations from different vendors.

Unfortunately I can't point out anything more specific than that, but whereever possible I'd prefer to either use local storage or raw iSCSI

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe :  After using Mariadb on NFS for a while, we found blocking issues too and ended up moving the database to mounted drive. Unfortunately, I could also not find the root cause. Perhaps, it is related to the the way IT configured the NFS drives but I don't know for sure.